# Endless Confusion Deriving the Sigmoid Function

Tags: python, neural-network, derivative

```
def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
  return x * (1 - x)
```

I'm learning how about neural networks from the simple neural network example: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/10/simple-neural-network-python.html

```
#Let's say 
x = 2
y = sigmoid(x)
y
Output: 0.8807970779778823

slope = sigmoid_derivative(y)
slope
Output: 0.10499358540350662
```

Now if m * x = y

slope * x = y

0.10499358540350662 * 2 = 0.2099871708 ?

The numbers don't add up and I have a feeling I am fundamentally misunderstanding this whole process.  Is there any assistance you can offer?  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is known from calculus, the statement

slope * x = y

is true only for a linear function, which sigmoid obviously isn't, especially around 2. The only thing you should expect is that

sigmoid_derivative(sigmoid(x0)) * (x1 - x0) + sigmoid(x0) = sigmoid(x1) + eps

where eps is a small error such that the smaller is |x1 - x0|, the smaller is |eps|.

You can easily check it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I feel like I can’t move on in my study of machine learning until I figure this out. I’m trying to figure out how the output of the derivative function matches to the original x value.  

If you’ve already explained this I apologize.  The problem is that I’m just getting my feet wet with calculus. I’m going to accept your answer but is there any way you can explain this to me like I am completely naïve?  Thank you.

Comment: You should read some good calculus book. I doubt I will be able to explain better.

Comment: Or you can consult Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Explanations